Keep only species name in FASTA header
I tried coding in Bash with the Awk and sed commands but didn't get the desired output. I have a text file with the following contents:
>AC201869.46386.47908 Regiella insecticola
AGAGTTTGATCATGGCTCAGATTGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAACACATGCAAGTCGAGCGGCAGCGGGGAGTAGCTTGCTACTCTGCCGGCGAGCGGC
>JQ765428.1.1430 Pantoea dispersa
GCAGCTACACATGCAAGTCGAACGGCAGCACAGAAGAGCTTGCTCTTTGGGTGGCGAGTGGCGGACGGGTGAGTAATGTCTGGGAAACTGCCCGATGGA

I need output like the following.
>Regiella insecticola
AGAGTTTGATCATGGCTCAGATTGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAACACATGCAAGTCGAGCGGCAGCGGGGAGTAGCTTGCTACTCTGCCGGCGAGCGGC
>Pantoea dispersa
GCAGCTACACATGCAAGTCGAACGGCAGCACAGAAGAGCTTGCTCTTTGGGTGGCGAGTGGCGGACGGGTGAGTAATGTCTGGGAAACTGCCCGATGGA

I tried some commands like these but they didn't work.
sed 's/[1-9]/./g' silva_species_assignment_v132.fa -> textfile.txt 


@Friedrich Your edit removed the FASTA header marker. I have fixed that, but probably take care with edits going forward. (It would of course help if the OP could identify the file format.)

@tripleee thanks for pointing out and fixing it. I was under the misconception that blockquotes had been used instead of code fences. We see that so frequently. It never occurred to me that the >  could be part of the data. Shame on me.

No worries, and thanks for following up.

Please take a moment to accept the answer that worked for you - just click the checkmark beside it. See What should I do when someone answers my question?

This might help: sed 's/>[^ ]*/>/' file.fasta

The following simple sed script will remove everything after > up through the first space.
sed 's/^>[^ ]* />/' file.fasta >newfile.fasta

In your attempt, [1-9] would replace any non-zero digit, but that's obviously not a useful pattern for this particular task. If you wanted to target stretches of uppercase alphabetics followed by digits and dots and ending with a space, that would be something like
sed -E 's/[A-Z]+[0-9.]+ //'

where the -E selects a more modern regex dialect so that you can use + for "one or more repetitions, as many as possible".
If you want an Awk solution, maybe somtething like
awk '/^>/ { $1=">" } 1' file.fasta >newfile.fasta

(though this will leave a space after >).
All three of these work with the examples you have provided; if you have more complex examples where the species name is not simply the text after the first space, probably ask a new question with more precise requirements.

@Abhisek if this answer worked for you, consider accepting it using the v-shaped button next to it.

You could pollute your data with a backspace character to "eliminate" that space visually if that helps... awk '/^>/ { $1=">"; $2="\b"$2 } 1' file -- but I'd just leave the space unless it's REALLY important to get rid of it. :)

It's not hard to write a better Awk script but I wanted to keep it really simple.

I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let file.txt content be
>AC201869.46386.47908 Regiella insecticola
AGAGTTTGATCATGGCTCAGATTGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAACACATGCAAGTCGAGCGGCAGCGGGGAGTAGCTTGCTACTCTGCCGGCGAGCGGC
>JQ765428.1.1430 Pantoea dispersa
GCAGCTACACATGCAAGTCGAACGGCAGCACAGAAGAGCTTGCTCTTTGGGTGGCGAGTGGCGGACGGGTGAGTAATGTCTGGGAAACTGCCCGATGGA

then
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[A-Z][a-z].*"}{print NF?(">"$1):$0}' file.txt

gives output
>Regiella insecticola
AGAGTTTGATCATGGCTCAGATTGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAACACATGCAAGTCGAGCGGCAGCGGGGAGTAGCTTGCTACTCTGCCGGCGAGCGGC
>Pantoea dispersa
GCAGCTACACATGCAAGTCGAACGGCAGCACAGAAGAGCTTGCTCTTTGGGTGGCGAGTGGCGGACGGGTGAGTAATGTCTGGGAAACTGCCCGATGGA

Explanation: as names starts with uppercase letter followed by lowercase letters, I instruct GNU AWK that field consist of uppercase letter, followed by lowercase letter, followed by zero-or-more any character. I use so-called ternary operator to print depending on if there is is at least 1 field. If there is at least one field I output said field prefixed with >, otherwise I output whole line ($0) as-is. Disclaimer: this solution assumes names consists of only ASCII character and 1st letter of name is always uppercase and 2nd letter of name is lowercase.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

Perhaps note that FPAT is specifically a GNU Awk extension, and not portable to standard Awk.
